# Can I create a dynamic class in Realm at runtime?

Tags: ios, realm

I want to create a runtime class based on JSON from a server. Can I create a Realm subclass at runtime that will store data in a table of Realm?

Comment: Have a look at [Dynamic Object schema Swift](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3242)

Comment: Nice one thanks @DávidPásztor may be I can get help from this.

Comment: @VivekLathiya were you able to achieve this in Swift? I am using the latest RealmSwift version and I don't see an option. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not sure with the Swift or Objective-C. But I have a solution to this for Java (Android). You need to use `DynamicRealmObject` and `RealmObjectSchema` for the same.

For example,

```
    DynamicRealm dynamicRealm = DynamicRealm.getInstance(App.getConfiguration());
    dynamicRealm.beginTransaction();
    DynamicRealmObject dyEvent = dynamicRealm.createObject("Event");
    RealmObjectSchema eventSchama = dynamicRealm.getSchema().get("Event");
    if (!eventSchama.hasField("content")) {
        DebugLog.i("eventSchama.has not Field content");
        eventSchama.addField("content", String.class);
    } else {
        DebugLog.i("eventSchama.hasField content");
    }
    RealmResults<DynamicRealmObject> dyEventResult = dynamicRealm.allObjects("Event");
    DebugLog.i("dyEventResult.size:" + dyEventResult.size());
    dyEvent.setString("name", "testName_" + dyEventResult.size());
    dyEvent.setString("content", "testContent_" + dyEventResult.size());

    dynamicRealm.commitTransaction();
```

The above example is for Android, but I am sure you might get the same reference for Swift or Objective-C as well.

Please check-out [this conversation](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2547) for the same.

Comment: What is **App.getConfiguration()**??